# Replace last occurrence of number with * using regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like "Test.1.Value.2.Configuration.3.Enable" , in which i want to replace only the last occurrence of the number '3' to '*'. the number may be any valid integer. Right row i did it by splitting the value to array and replacing array length-2 nd value to * and rejoining it. Would like to know if we can do it by using regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, easily:

```js
str = "Test.1.Value.2.Configuration.3.Enable";
newstr = str.replace(/\d+(?=\.[^.]+$)/, '*')
console.log(newstr)
```

"Replace all the digits that are followed by a period and some non-periods before the end of the string with an asterisk."

Comment: But the regex is not working if the string is like this "Device.test.point.1.params.enabled"

Comment: Oh, didn't think that's what you want (because your original code also doesn't do the right thing in this case). In that case, use `/\d+(?=\.\D+$)/`, "replace all the digits that are followed by a period and some non-digits before the end of string with an asterisk".

Answer (score 0):

`const newStr = str.split(".").map((e, i, arr) => i === arr.length - 2 ? "*" : e).join(".");`